# SqlException: Data modification failed on system-versioned table because transaction time was earlier than period start time for affected records

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019

I m getting the above error when running the Web Job in multi-threaded environment. I m calling one stored procedure to perform some action, stored procedure has code which Inserts/Updates/Delete records from pretty big **temporal tables**(3-4M records[not sure if its relevant here]). Every time the job is run it deals with(Insert/Update) around 40K-80K records based on condition. When the single thread is running everything goes fine. But as soon as number of parallel jobs count is set to 2 or more I m getting the error. From initial analysis seems like issue is with Auto generated column values with for SysStartTime and SysEndTime in history table. I have tried one of the solution from internet to reduce 1 second from the date to be saved in those columns as below

`DEFAULT (dateadd(second,(-1),sysutcdatetime()))`

But its not working. I have read few articles where it says temporal tables does not work properly  in multi-threaded environment. Now I m not sure why the issue is happening and how to resolve this in multi-threaded environment.
Can someone here please help me understanding the reason behind the error and how to fix it.

NOTE: I can't make my code to run on single thread. Minimum three threads are required. Converting to single thread is not solution  in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS SQL temporal table update failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672573/ms-sql-temporal-table-update-failure)

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT I can't make my code single threaded. So that's not the solution for me.

Comment: if you do serializable + explicit transactions (begin trans, update query, commit), it should mitigate the issue.

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT Thanks for suggestion. I will try that and update here.

Comment: retry should also be an effective model if you can't use isolation level to solve.

Comment: Any updates on this please?